# How to improve a recursive sorting algorithm that is already O(n)?

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I have this recursive sorting algorithm I'm using for an assignment, and my teacher said that there's an *easy* way to improve the running time of my algorithm... But I can't figure out what it is, at all. Unless I'm mistaken, the complexity for the algorithm is O(n)? I'm not sure since we didn't learn how to calculate the complexity of recursive methods in class. Here's the code:

```
public static void MyAlgorithm(int[] A, int n){
    boolean done = true;
    int j = 0;
    while (j <= n - 2){
        if (A[j] > A[j + 1]) {
            swap(A,j,j+1);
            done= false;
        }
        j++;
    }
    j = n - 1;
    while (j >= 1){
        if (A[j] < A[j - 1]) {
            swap(A,j-1,j);
            done=false;
        }
        j--; 
    }

    if (!done)
        MyAlgorithm(A, n);
    else
        return;
}
```

The only thing I can think of would be adding a if(done) return;  after the first loop but it only saves the program from doing a few other operations. Oh and the swap method is basically just:

```
public static void swap(int[] arr, int pos1, int pos2){
    int temp = arr[pos1];
    arr[pos1] = arr[pos2];
    arr[pos2] = temp;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest using descriptive variable names. This is really hard to read as is. Single letter variable names are avoided in industry.

Comment: It's not O(n) - there isn't any O(n) sorting algorithm.

Comment: @user93353 Not comparison based ones anyway...

Comment: @user93353 It is O(n), but it is not a general purpose sorting algorithm, since it only works for almost sorted arrays.

Comment: @jameson In a sorting algorithm, the variable name `a` is well-established and OK. So are the single-letter names `i` and `j` in short loops.

Comment: @RolandIllig This is Java, I doubt such vague names would be accepted. Those variable names should be revised to arrayToBeSorted, indexI and indexJ. /s

Comment: @Jacob Have a look at the sorting implementations in java.util.Array. There they use short variable names. The `ToBeSorted` and `Index` parts of your suggested variable names are redundant, so they should be left out.

Comment: @RolandIllig Note the "/s" at the end of my post. I'm just poking fun at Java, I wouldn't expect such stupid names to be used in practice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To start, no sorting algorithm can be performed in O(n) using comparisons. As a general rule, all sorting algorithms take AT LEAST O(n*log(n)) time.

The sort you appear to be using is something akin to the cocktail shaker sort, or bidirectional bubble sort. It runs in O(n^2) time. You should definitely research the methods you use and consider why you use them, and also learn how to properly classify things in big O notation.

I imagine your teacher means that you should call the sort as MyAlgorithm(a, n-1). Notice how in your first loop it goes through the entire array? This means that the last element will already be sorted when that loop exits. Similarly, you could add a start index and increment it each time. For example, revised code:

```
public static void MyAlgorithm(int[] A, int start, int n){
    boolean done = true;
    int j = start;
    while (j <= n - 2){
        if (A[j] > A[j + 1]) {
            swap(A,j,j+1);
            done= false;
        }
        j++;
    }
    j = n - 1;
    while (j >= start+1){
        if (A[j] < A[j - 1]) {
            swap(A,j-1,j);
            done=false;
        }
        j--; 
    }

    if (!done)
        MyAlgorithm(A, start+1, n-1);
    else
        return;
}
```

Then you can call this using: MyAlgorithm(my_array, 0, my_array.length)

Keep in mind that this is still not a fantastic sorting algorithm, and if you ever need to sort large amount of data, you should consider using something faster.

Comment: Incorrect on the facts: All *comparison-based* sorting algorithms are at least O(n log n), but special-cased sorts can run in linear time (for example, radix sort).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. I'm aware of radix and counting sort, and O(n) complexity, but I thought I was pretty clear that the basis of O(n*log(n)) was exclusive to the comparison model.